# A function that implies true when a and b have the same value

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get true when both a and b are true or both of them are false. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
imply :: (a -> Bool, b -> Bool) -> Bool
a = False
b = True
imply (a, a) = True
imply (b, b) = True
imply _ = False
```

Comment: Your terminology is weird: a function can not "imply" anything. I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Are you trying to check if two values are equal? If so, `(==)` is a function which compares any two values whose type is in the `Eq` typeclass. (Note that you can't check if two functions are equal, so you need some typeclass constraint.)

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want to write `imply :: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool`? Currently your function is trying to test whether two functions are equal, which seems decidedly odd, to say the least.

Comment: The signature of your function suggests that as input you take a 2-tuple where the first item is a function that maps `a`s to `Bool`s, and the second `b`s to `Bool`s. But that does not seems to be the case for your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to make a guess about what you want, since it seems like you are struggling with the basics of Haskell syntax.  Consider going through [a tutorial](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials) if you are not already.

I agree with [@bradrn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784011/a-function-that-implies-true-when-a-and-b-have-the-same-value/58784326#comment103851827_58784011) that the function you are looking for is probably this one:

```
imply :: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool
imply (True, True)   = True
imply (False, False) = True
imply _ = False
```

I could explain all sorts of things about what you did, but I figured you just needed to see an example of how this looks.  I'm happy to answer any questions you have about it in the comments.

To use this function, say, after loading the file in `ghci`, you type:

```
ghci> imply (True, False)
False
ghci> imply (False, False)
True
```

Note that in Haskell the convention is to define functions *curried*, so we would instead see

```
imply :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
imply True True = True
...

ghci> imply True False
False
```

But the two versions are *(almost)* equivalent.

Comment: Why is this function called `imply`? As you wrote it, it does not correspond to the truth table of implication, but of equivalence. Should it?

Comment: @chi, look at the edit history of the question & you'll get it.  (But I agree this name needs improvement)